# input field validation does not work under internet explorer 11 why

Tags: php, html, jscript

Unable to get the following code to do field validation for email and to accept only certain emails input as per my code..this code works in all browsers accept Internet explorer 11, how can adopt this code to work under I.E 11 to only accept from certain email format addresses...

under I.E. 11 - it checks for empty field ok but i can not get the email pattern to work (html5) how can i get it to work under IE 11, it works on other browsers okay, thanks in advance...singhy

```js
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Subscribe"])){ //name of submit button
    foreach($_POST as $fieldName => $value){
        if($fieldName!="Subscribe"){ //if not submit button
            $fieldValue=$value;
            if($fieldValue == "") {
                echo "Cannot leave ".$fieldName." blank";
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<script>
function IsEmpty(){
  if(document.forms['frm'].email.value == "")
  {
    alert("empty field");
    return false;
  }
    return true;
}
</script>

<form name="frm" class="test" method="post" action="myform.php" >
<fieldset><legend><strong>test</strong></legend> 
<p>testing my code...</p>

<p><label for="email">Email address:</label>
<input title="enter email" required="required" name="email" type='email' pattern=".+(@hotmail.com)|.+(@gmail.com)" required />

</p>
 <input id="insert" onclick="return IsEmpty();" style="float: right;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe" />
</fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to support just hotmail and gmail accounts? Any reason you chose the `pattern` attribute? Can you do with regular expressions?

Comment: Hi, yes just the hotmail and gmail accounts , yes regular expressions are fine as well

Comment: It's working on my IE 11. Does it give you any error?

Comment: No errors naija - its not validating the email required format !!, it just accepts any email address under I.E11 !, ideally it should display a message for user to say that the email format is wrong, under ie 11 it does not do it !, however it works under all other browsers...anyhelp would be ideal to get it working under IE11 thanks

Comment: Can't say why it's not working on your system. It's working on my system, with both the empty and the email format validation working perfectly.

Comment: ok thanks for trying, i am using v11.0.96, could it be my settings within IE !

Answer (score 2):

managed to sort this problem by adding the following code at top

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

this renders the I.E to edge and all of my message output and email validation is working now...thanks again for all those helped me, take care singhy