# How are IE11 users bypassing HTML5 validation?

Tags: html, validation

I have a form with HTML5 validation throughout - like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<label>Name: <input type="text" name="Name" required></label>
<label>Address: <input type="text" name="Address" required></label>
<label>Zip: <input type="text" name="Zip" required></label>
<label>Message: <input type="text" name="Message"></label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

But I've noticed that some forms are coming in partially filled out. I checked server logs and it looks like these are coming from IE11 on Windows 10.

I've been trying to reproduce the behavior but so far the only way I've been able to bypass the HTML5 validation in IE11 is to use the Developer Tools to manually add the `novalidate` property directly to the form before clicking Submit. Are people really going to this length or is there some other browser setting that would be more commonplace?

The users in question are unlikely to be very advanced, but I could possibly imagine a corporate security policy setting somewhere disabling form validation.

Comment: Either way--you cannot rely on client-side validation alone, essentially ever. Input should always be validated on the server side as well. You can't even rely on your page being rendered as you've rendered it.

Comment: Always re-validate submitted data on the server.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm already proposing server-side validation, but still curious as to how this can happen. HTML5 is not javascript, so disabling javascript client-side shouldn't have this effect. As an example.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32587116/input-field-validation-does-not-work-under-internet-explorer-11-why

Comment: Much thanks @FAKETAXI I hadn't seen that one before. Looks like a really good interim solution.